# Android wifi packet sniffer

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I'm looking for android sniffer projects... Is there any sniffers for Android like Kismet for Linux??????

[a link] http://www.kismetwireless.net/documentation.shtml

Any information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is wire shark for android if that's what your talking about...

Comment: it's similar.... I want to find sniffer to capture all traffic of 802.11 b,g,n around my phone and then analize it.